# Load code from string - PHP

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to add functionality in php from string instead linking apache to dll file?

Let's say I use .dll compiled from C source, find pointer from desired function, copy that shellcode, encode it into base64 string, and load it into php code as string.
 Which php function should I use to execute that shellcode then, and pass parameters from php? Also I guess that such script would be machine dependent, because shellcode runs on OS.

Answer (score 0):

Creatr file like `my_exec.php`:

```
<?php

//$string = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
$string = $_GET['string'];

$command = base64_decode( $str );

exec( $command, $results );

?>
```

Now access it like: `http://mysite.com/my_exec.php?string=VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==`

If I understand what you mean.

But note! This has a **huge** security risk!

Comment: exec() is the only function that could serve for this? Also I don't know if it can execute part of shellcode (one function). It requires exe file.

Comment: There are more possibilities to execute a shell script, read more about that in PHP manual: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+shell+executions

Answer (score 0):

```
$code = <<<'EOT'
    $var = 'foo';
EOT;

eval($code);

echo $var; //Foo
```

You can populate `$code` from `file_get_contents()` if you wish.

**BEWARE**: `eval()` can be a HUGE security risk.

Comment: You haven't read my post. I know of eval, it is loading php code. I am talking about loading compiled shellcode.

Comment: I did read your question and took the time to answer. I misinterpreted your use of shellcode as an example.